# Are non-Jews allowed / invited to attend orthodox weddings?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, marriage

I am a Reform Jew and ill-equipped to answer this question from a close friend who is not Jewish.  Apparently, my (non-Jewish) friend is NOT invited to the (Orthodox) wedding of the daughter of a close friend & co-worker.  It was explained to my friend that Orthodox Jews simply don't allow or invite non-Jews to their weddings.  I told my friend, whose feelings were genuinely hurt, that I had never heard that tradition.  As far as I know, anyone can invite anyone they want to their wedding.  But, to repeat, I was raised Reform and am no expert on Orthodox traditions.  You are the experts, right?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Keep in mind, that few of us here are rabbis, if that's what you mean by stating that we are "experts". I'm not inclined to fully agree with stating "It was explained to my friend that Orthodox Jews simply don't allow or invite non-Jews to their weddings." I don't think that there is any prohibition. As a matter of fact, I have been to numerous Orthodox weddings where the bride and / or groom invited some Gentile co-workers. I agree that it is not overly common to invite Gentiles, but, I think it's simply b/c many just don't associate with them as close friends.

Comment: Welcome! Consider reading this short useful [Beginners' Guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775) to the site.

Comment: @sabbahillel To whoever voted to close, the case behind the question may be unknown, or unknowable, but that doesn't affect the question itself, which is quite clear.

Comment: @sabbahillel You seem to be making stuff up. I see no indication of this whatsoever, and neither does anyone else. You are just making vague claims about what the OP really wants, etc. etc. Rather than simply addressing the question actually asked.

Comment: @mevaqesh The OP said what he thought had been said to the nonJewish friend and that his feelings were hurt. If the question had been asked without those details, I would not have considered this. However, this does appear to need more details as to what was said and what is going on.

Comment: @sabbahillel You dont seem to be reading the question or my comments. The _question_ is totally clear: "Are non-Jews allowed / invited to attend orthodox weddings?". The _motivation_ is indeed a secondhand comment that we cannot know exactly. This is the equivalent of confusing gidrei mitsvot with taamei hamitsvot.

Comment: @sabbahillel | I don't think there is any other way to phrase this other than what I have. It seems obvious to me (and apparently everyone else). If it isnt to you, I don't think there is much else to be said. (Except that we can only answer questions asked; not ones we presume someone meant to ask).

Comment: I’m with @mevaqesh. This question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Was the non-Jewish friend in question male or female? I’m curious whether, since there is no actual problem with inviting non-Jews to Jewish weddings (see mevaqesh’s answer), if the Jewish family was concerned about tznius and felt it was easier (kinder?) to tell her Jews don’t invite non-Jews rather than tell her what she’s allowed to wear and risk her not showing up appropriately nevertheless.

Answer (score 5):

It is difficult to rigorously prove the negative, but as someone who has much familiarity with Orthodox Jews and Orthodox weddings, I can state that there is no such prohibition. Non-Jews at Orthodox weddings are not so rare (although admittedly not overly common).

[R. Yehuda Amihai](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99_(%D7%A8%D7%91)) affirms  [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94/), that it is permissible.

Comment: It is important to note that Orthodox Jews tend to be fairly cloistered (the degree being largely dependent on which sub-group they belong to). Accordingly, generally the significant majority of their friends will be other Jews. This will reflect itself in who will be found at a wedding.

Comment: But just because it is permissible by Jewish Law does not mean that all Orthodox Jews will invite non-Jews to their weddings. Some might feel uncomfortable doing so, either out of their own opinions or what their community might think. It would be interesting to know if the Jew in the OP was from a Hasidic stiebel. That might change things a bit.

Comment: @ezra of course.